# dlopen returns with File Not Found although file exist

Tags: c, linux

I am using the following code -

```
pxSFunc->handle = dlopen(psFilePath, RTLD_LAZY);
if (!pxSFunc->handle) {
     printf("%s Ignored loading the lib: %s\n", dlerror(), psFilePath);
```

Where psFilePath points on a valid path (readable and accessable).

After running this section, I receive the following error:

```
File not found Ignored loading the lib: /usr/lib/libnetwork.so
```

I wander about what debug tools should I use to debug this issue?

I added all relevant paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and running 'ldd' on this lib shows no issues.
Maybe someone have any ideas on what can this issue be related to?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This is taken from man page of dlopen - 
       If the object specified by filename has dependencies on other shared
       objects, then these are also automatically loaded by the dynamic
       linker using the same rules.  (This process may occur recursively, if
       those objects in turn have dependencies, and so on.)

Comment: Try `perror(psFilePath);`

Comment: Make sure the architectures match (i.e. x86 vs amd64).

Comment: It does. I'm using x86-i386

Comment: Then I can only recommend to `strace` yor executable and see which `open` operation (or other interesting operation) fails.

Comment: For me - the problem was eventually with procd, which didn't compile fully due to environment issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to see all the debugging information from the linker to see where exactly it fails with:

```
 $ export LD_DEBUG=all
```

and run your program. There's also `LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT` if you want to redirect the debug information to a file. You can see more info from the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

And you can also use `ldd` to see the dependency list:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/libnetwork.so
```

The output will be obvious to understand and it'll tell if any of dependencies are missing.

Comment: A follow up question for you - After adding all relevant paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and run ldd on the .so - all dependencies are satisfied. However, I still receive 'File not found' as a return error from dlopen. Any other thoughts?